# subset columns based on value in additional column R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c1', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h1'),
                  T_10_12 = c(11, 15, 14, 14, 13, 16, 15, 12, 11, 12),
                  T_12_14 = c(12, 16, 16, 16, 14, 17, 16.5, 13, 12, 12),
                  T_14_16 = c(13, 18, 17.5, 16.5, 15, 18, 17.2, 13, 13, 14),
                  T_out = c(10.5, 12.3, 14.5, 15.1, 15, 13, 12, 13, 13, 14))
```

I wish to subset the columns 'T_10_12', 'T_12_14', 'T_14_16' so that only one value is take for each row . The column from which to select the value is dictated by the number in column 'T_out'. If 'T_out'=10.5, then the value from T_10_12 is assigned to a new variable 'T_in'. If 'T_out' = 14.5, then the value in 'T_14_16' is assigned to 'T_in'. The output should look like this:

```
   ID T_in T_out
1   a 11.0  10.5
2   b 16.0  12.3
3   c 17.5  14.5
4  c1 16.5  15.1
5   d 15.0  15.0
6   e 17.0  13.0
7   f 15.0  12.0
8   g 16.5  13.0
9   h 13.0  13.0
10 h1 14.0  14.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(T_in = case_when(
    T_out == 10.5 ~ T_10_12,
    T_out >= 10.5 & T_out < 12.5 ~ T_10_12,
    T_out >= 12.5 & T_out < 14.5 ~ T_12_14,
    .default = T_14_16
  )) %>%
  select(ID, T_in, T_out)
```

```
 ID T_in T_out
1   a 11.0  10.5
2   b 15.0  12.3
3   c 17.5  14.5
4  c1 16.5  15.1
5   d 15.0  15.0
6   e 17.0  13.0
7   f 15.0  12.0
8   g 13.0  13.0
9   h 12.0  13.0
10 h1 12.0  14.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `findInterval` (since you can use `12` and `14` in the column names to classify the intervals for values in `T_out`)

```
transform(
    df1,
    T_in = df1[-1][cbind(
        seq_along(T_out),
        findInterval(T_out, c(12, 14)) + 1
    )]
)[c("ID", "T_in", "T_out")]
```

gives

```
   ID T_in T_out
1   a 11.0  10.5
2   b 16.0  12.3
3   c 17.5  14.5
4  c1 16.5  15.1
5   d 15.0  15.0
6   e 17.0  13.0
7   f 16.5  12.0
8   g 13.0  13.0
9   h 12.0  13.0
10 h1 14.0  14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic approach that checks the condition against the values from `cur_column`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  reframe(
    ID, 
    T_in = rowSums(across(matches("T_\\d+"), ~ 
      if_else(as.numeric(str_extract(cur_column(), "T_(\\d+)", 1)) < T_out & 
              as.numeric(str_extract(cur_column(), "(\\d+)$", 1) >= T_out), .x, 0))), 
    T_out)
```

output

```
   ID T_in T_out
1   a 11.0  10.5
2   b 16.0  12.3
3   c 17.5  14.5
4  c1 16.5  15.1
5   d 15.0  15.0
6   e 17.0  13.0
7   f 15.0  12.0
8   g 13.0  13.0
9   h 12.0  13.0
10 h1 12.0  14.0
```